# Is this a correct implementation of the Euclidean Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, webassembly

I've tried to implement the Euclidean algorithm in AEC. One quirky problem is that AEC doesn't support local variables except as function arguments. You can see it live [here](https://flatassembler.github.io/euclidTest.html). Here is the code:

```
Function gcd(Integer32 a, Integer32 b) Which Returns Integer32 Does
    //So, this will be Euclid's algorithm. But, first, let's deal with
    //the edge cases.
    If a<0 Then
        a:=a*-1; //Write in such a way that it will expose as many potential
                 //bugs in the compiler as you can.
    EndIf
    If b<0 Then
        b:=b/-1;
    EndIf
    If a=0 or b=0 Then
        Return 0;
    EndIf
    //And now goes the 2'300 years-old algorithm:
    While not(b=0) Loop
        If a>b Then
            a:=mod(a,b);
        Else
            If a=0 Then
                Return b;
            EndIf
            b:=mod(b,a);
        EndIf
    EndWhile
    Return a;
EndFunction
```

So, is this a correct implementation of the algorithm? As far as I've tested it, it appears to work, however, I am not sure. The subtraction-based Euclidean algorithm is very slow, and the conventional modulo-based one can't be implemented without a third variable.

Comment: There is a weird edge case for -2147483648, does that matter? It would have been that way independently of implementing the main loop with a third variable or not

Comment: The case „If a=0 or b=0 Then“ is not needed, because then the loop will not iterate and you return a which is null in that case.